# How to import a module's variable in python？

Tags: python

I want to import a module named "`config`" and I want import `config.times`. But in my code, `times` is a element in a list `name_list`, it means:

`name_list = ['times','date','hours']`.

When I want to use `config.times` ,I try `config.name_list[0]`. Of course there is an error `" 'module' object has no attribute 'name_list'"`. So how can I fix it? Thanks.
***---More details:***
My code is: config.py,main.py .In config.py, times = ['00:00:00','12:00:00'],and in main.py ,name_list = ['times','date','hours'],I want exec `now = config.times` in main.py.

Comment: all these explanation you gave can`t replace posting your config module code...i bet this is because of how you defined your config code...but how can i know if you don't post it...

Comment: My code is: `config.py,main.py` .In `config.py`, times = ['00:00:00','12:00:00'],and in `main.py` ,name_list = ['times','date','hours'],I want exec `now = config.times` in main.py.

Comment: can you add them to the question?the main and config file codes?i think its the natural way to ask question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to access the `times` variable from a module you've imported, but you want that name (`times`) to come from another variable, rather than being hard coded.

That's possible to do in a few ways. The easiest is probably to use the `getattr` function to get the attribute from the module object:

```
import config

name = "times" # or wherever, e.g. name_list[0]

results = getattr(config, name) # will get a reference to config.times
```

I'm not sure doing this is really a great idea though. Generally speaking, variable names (such as `times` in the `config` module) should be intended for programmers to interpret. They should not be data. If you want to look up data by name, you should generally use a dictionary to store the keys and values, rather than using the namespace of a module.

So for instance, your `config` module could have a dictionary named `data`, and you could move your current `times` value to `data['times']`. Then looking up a value by name is just a dictionary lookup: `config.data[name]`.

Comment: That worked and many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try  using following in main.py :

```
from config import times
```

or

```
name_list = ['config.times','date','hours']
```

EDITED from here on for more clarification
and then use :

```
eval(name_list[0]) # for evaluating config.times
```

## I hope this is more clear

please remove the downvote.

Comment: That's what OP tried. See his explanation in comments. it would make it clearer.

Comment: are you @gonczor talking about
    My code is: config.py,main.py .In config.py, times = ['00:00:00','12:00:00'],and in main.py ,name_list = ['times','date','hours'],I want exec now = config.times in main.py. – Peng He 2 hours

Then there is a difference in what I wrote and his code.
Please recheck.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I thought it was some different matter too.

Comment: @gonczor the code above works for me.
OP is not using it properly
He has    now   =    'config.times'    and    now is not being used anywhere in his code , whereas I have    used     'config.times'  as first element in   name_list   =  ( **name_list = ['config.times','date','hours']** )

Comment: @gonczor if you agree with my explanation then please **upvote my answer instead of downvote** .
Thanks very much .

Comment: I haven't downvoted it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147043/discussion-between-gurdyal-and-gonczor).